# Use output of one pubsub as a lookup in another pub sub input in dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using Java dataflow.
I am trying to read data from one pubsub and converting it into PCollectionView of Map<String, String>, So that i can use it in another pubsub's input as a sideInput.

The combiner is not producing any output.

Is it correct approach ?

Used Window in lookup pubsub and then combined it globally to form a Map<String, String>and finally converted it to singletonView()

Comment: Can you share more details on your issue and share your code ?